# How do I correct file not found error in Jupyter notenook using pandas I have made multiple attempts and believe path to be correcct?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, filenotfounderror

Below is the image of the error message I continuously receive:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF0Rq.png)

Comment: Be sure you have your file in the folder you called Resources. Be aware of capital naming the folder and files. Otherwise, just move your file next to your notebook and load ii like pd.read_csv("your_file.csv"). Regards.

Comment: Thank you! The file was in the Resources folder but Im sure I made an error in some way. I just managed to fix this by moving files and rooting jupyter to the exact folder and simply calling the csv file directly. I appreciate your help.